# Switch statement (Character)

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a switch statement that takes the letter grade and returns the corresponding GPA; however, it throws a cannot-find-symbol error for the letters (A, B, C, D & F)! I've checked the javaDocs for guidance but couldn't find something wrong. What is causing this error?

```
switch (grade) {
        case A:  nv[i] = 4; //nv = numerical value
                 break;
        case B:  nv[i] = 3;
                 break;
        case C:  nv[i] = 2;
                 break;
        case D:  nv[i] = 1;
                 break;
        case F:  nv[i] = 0;
                 break;
    }
```

Comment: There is no question ...

Comment: I modified my question.. sorry!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`A` isn't a valid character literal - `'A'` is.

So you want:

```
switch (grade) {
    case 'A':  nv[i] = 4; //nv = numerical value
             break;
    case 'B':  nv[i] = 3;
             break;
    case 'C':  nv[i] = 2;
             break;
    case 'D':  nv[i] = 1;
             break;
    case 'F':  nv[i] = 0;
             break;
}
```

You should also probably have a default case for situations where the grade isn't one of those.

Oh, and your code could also be written as:

```
nv[i] = "FDCBA".indexOf(grade);
```

with a check for `nv[i]` being -1 afterwards (meaning that the grade wasn't in that set).

Comment: So quickly you got the question :)

Comment: I don't understand how to check for `nv[i]` being -1? what do you mean by that?

Comment: @InspiringProgramming: I mean that in my simpler approach, `indexOf` will return -1 if `grade` isn't in found... so `nv[i]` will be -1. So to detect that, you'd use `if (nv[i] == -1) { ... }`